# Display server progress

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a login form through through which the user will login into my application. i have a server whos services are made in WCF. i am using the services on the server to authenticates the user. i have to display a server progress time at the client end.how is this possible??.please help

thnx in advance.

Comment: You want to show a progress bar while the user is being authenticated?

Answer (score 1):

And how can you measure progress on the server? Progress is usually shown for processing which can be measured. For example if you need process 1000 records you can show progress but if you need authenticate user you simply can't because there is no constant measurable increment in the processing. Moreover measuring progress requires duplex communication = a client will request something and the server will send back callbacks informing about increments. But the server is able to send callback only when the client is authenticated so you can't send progress of authentication back to client. Btw. authentication should take no more then few seconds so there is no reason to show progress. Use some animated gif (in case of web application) or change cursor (in case of WinForms or WPF) to show processing.

Comment: Assuming the authentication process consists of several steps it is imaginable that one could say "I have 4 steps and I just completed step one so I have a 25% progress". Why do you say you cannot send progress information back without authentication? I would say you should be able to send back progress information to a client that sent a request (be it a login request)... I agree the login should be fast enough but if for some reason it is not?

Answer (score 0):

If you control and can change the WCF service than one possibility would be to make it a duplex service and have the service post back progress information to the client.

See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) for more information on Duplex Services

Another possibility would be to call the Login operation asynchronously from the client and provide a method in the WCF service to poll for the progress from client. for info on calling Service operations asynchrouneously please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx).

Or maybe the simplest approach, call the Login operation asynchronously from the client and present a dialog to the user with some animation and a "Logging in... Please wait!"

To be honest I would take the simple approach...